# LibreOffice Writer, how to copy style from one document to another?

Tags: formatting, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

LibreOffice Writer Version: 7.0.4.2
Build ID: 00(Build:2)
I need copy style from one Writer document to another (all styles) to make formatting clone. How to make this? Tried varios guides, but without success, possibly due to LibreOffice versions vary.

Comment: "Tried vario[u]s guides..." Okay, but what did you try for example? Have you attempted Styles > Load Styles as described in the [help docs](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/load_styles.html)?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a over year, but for some reason this post pops up as the top result. David is correct, but the reason nothing changed might be because "Overwrite" in the Load Styles from Template window weren't selected. You also may need to go to `File>Templates>Edit Templates...` and edit the style in the .ott file and then re-load it `Styles>Load Styles from Template`.

If you edited Heading 2 in the styled document, you'll need to click Overwrite to get it to overwrite Heading 2 in the destination document.

I also selected "Page" and voila, the size and margins of the destination document changed as well.

[image: Load Styles from Template window]

Comment: The issue might also be that you directly edited something (e.g., selecting a heading and changed the font to 16pt) which overrides the any styles you see when you press F11 (e.g., having Heading 1 be size 14pt). The outcome would be a 16pt heading for that one you directly edited. Ctrl+M clears direct editing and yields to the styles. Press F5 to load the Navigator to find specific categories (e.g., Headings) and press Ctrl+M.

Answer (score 0):

Save the source Writer document, or a document with the styles in that document, as a template. Then go to `Styles > Load Styles...` in the destination Writer document and select the template saved from the source document. The styles from the source document should then be available in the destination document.

Comment: I tried this. No, this does not change anything in the destination Writer document.  Everything remains exactly as it was.